# showing undefined when trying to access the collection using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am trying to display all the documents in a collection called tutorial so i am using a simple code here's my code

```
const mongodb = require("mongodb");
const express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var conn = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
mongoClient.connect(conn, (err, client) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("connection estableshed");
    var db = client.db("mydb");
    var collection = db.collection("tutorial");
    collection.find().toArray((err, data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
    client.close();
  }
});
```

but the result i got undefined so what seems to be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with the callback, you can use then() method instead.

```
const mongodb = require("mongodb");
const express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var conn = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

mongoClient.connect(conn).then((err, client) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("connection established");
    var db = client.db("mydb");
    var collection = db.collection("tutorial");
    collection
      .find()
      .toArray()
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
    client.close();
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server started");
});
```

Comment: it doesn't display the documents it's only displays the schema

Comment: Hi, It has printed all information in the terminal. What are the documents you are referring to?

Comment: hey this the answer to my comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74582217/nodejs-doesnt-display-data-from-mongodb/74582408?noredirect=1#comment131649685_74582408

Comment: Glad to know you have the answer, good luck!